# Is it now possible to add more than one dashboard to the home page in Salesforce?

Tags: dashboard, home-page-layout

I would like to add more than one dashboard to the home page in Salesforce (at least would like to have 3 dashboards on the home page).

After reading many similar threads, I tried the suggestions given there.
One with a code:

```
<iframe src="/00000000000?isdtp=lt" frameborder="0" height="900" width="1280"></iframe>
```

It seems to be this doesn't work anymore after many releases in Salesforce. Threads that I found had the year 2013 or less. So I guess from 2013 this is not working anymore.
I also replaced the parte iframe by "location.href=", but it didn't work. I use Visualforce.

Though, I would appreciate if someone knows how to code that, so this can work. I have the Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 2):

At this time, customers are only able to put up to three dashboards components on their Homepage at a time.

As a workaround customers can customize their Homepage by selecting a different dashboards to display on their Homepage via the following click path: Name > Setup > My Personal Information > Change My Display.

However, if the customer would like to add multiple dashboards to the Homepage they can vote on this idea on the IdeaExchange:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000g5DWAAY